# Inequality to prove using LMVT

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove that $$1+x <e^x <1+xe^x $$ for $x\in (0,\infty) $using LMVT.

I can easily prove this using derivatives but how to do it using LMVT.

Comment: Yes @BAI.......

Comment: Er, LMVT is also using a derivative, isn't it ?

Comment: @Yves i mean direct differentiation taking $f (x) $ no internediate steps like $f (0)=0$ and all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=e^x-x-1$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

MVT: there exists $t\in (0,x)$ for which:
$$f'(t)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \Rightarrow e^t-1=\frac{e^x-x-1-0}{x-0} \Rightarrow e^x=1+xe^t>1+x, t>0.$$

Consider $f(x)=xe^x+1-e^x$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

MVT: there exists $t\in (0,x)$ for which:
$$f'(t)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} \Rightarrow te^t=\frac{xe^x+1-e^x-0}{x-0} \Rightarrow e^x=1+xe^x-txe^x<1+xe^x, t>0.$$

Comment: We can solve our problem by one step only. See please my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, yes, I had seen your and Fred's answers before posting mine. I just wanted to diversify and specify the answers. Respect.

Answer (score 3):

For $x>0$ we obtain:

$$\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0}=\left(e^x\right)'_{x=\theta x}=e^{\theta x},$$ where $0<\theta<1$, which exists by LMVT.

Thus, $$e^x=1+xe^{\theta x}$$ and we are done because
$$1+x<1+xe^{\theta x}<1+xe^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=e^x-x-1$ for $x \ge 0$. Then $f(0)=0$, hence, if $x>0$:

$f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=xf'(t)$ for some $t \in (0,x)$ (LMVT).

We have $xf'(t)=x(e^t-1)>0$.

The second inequality can be proved similar.